# DriveImage XML fails with a Windows Volume Shadow Service Error - dll missing?

Tags: windows-7, backup, vss, driveimagexml

My problem is exactly as reported in the post here
[See Previous Superuser question...](https://superuser.com/questions/119249/driveimage-xml-fails-with-a-windows-volume-shadow-service-error)

when it comes to looking at how it was resolved for that person it said to make sure that 'oleaut.dll' was registered.

my problem is i have oleaut32.dll but not oleaut.dll? Where can i get this from and where should it live? im guessing sysWOW64.

Should this have been installed originally by driveimageXML?

Its strange that it works fine backing up C: using vss but D: (which is a partition of the same drive) it gives the error on.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no oleaut.dll. The right name seems to be oleaut32.dll.

Information about this Microsoft DLL is found [here](http://www.auditmypc.com/process/oleaut32.asp).